# Can I in some way include a file with Redirects inside my <VirtualHost>

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, prestashop

I migrating a friends webshop from one system to another and trying to make all old urls point to the new ones.

So I got like 10Ks of lines like this:
Rewrite /a /b

I know that I can just add them to inside my `<VirtualHost>` but it will be hard to read the rest of the `<VirtualHost>` settings then.

The new webshop is Prestashop and it uses a .htaccess-file and has a `<textarea>` where you can add extra settings that you want to keep when you regenerate prestashops .htaccess-file.

So I tried to paste all my lines into the `<textarea>` but it has some kind of limit, so only like half of them where stored.

I can't just paste the lines into .htaccess with a text editor, because sometime you you change som settings in prestashop the .htaccess file needs to be generated and my manually added lines will be overwritten.

So what i'm looking for is a way to include a file with all the Redirects, inside my  or in the .htaccess.

Or config apache to load both .htaccess and .htacces2 or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh it was so easy, just added: Include "file.conf" inside my `<VirtualHost>` and all works great.